# RNN loss becomes NaN due to very large prediction values

Tags: optimization, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Below is the RNN that I build using Keras:

```
def RNN_keras(feat_num, timestep_num=100):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(BatchNormalization(input_shape=(timestep_num, feat_num)))
    model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(timestep_num, feat_num), output_dim=512, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())  
    model.add(LSTM(output_dim=128, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim=1, activation='linear'))) # sequence labeling

    rmsprop = RMSprop(lr=0.00001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                  optimizer=rmsprop,
                  metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    return model
```

The output is as following:

```
61267 in the training set
6808 in the test set

Building training input vectors ...
888 unique feature names
The length of each vector will be 888
Using TensorFlow backend.

Build model...

****** Iterating over each batch of the training data ******
# Each batch has 1280 examples
# The training data are shuffled at the beginning of each epoch.
Epoch 1/3 : Batch 1/48 | loss = 607.043823 | root_mean_squared_error = 24.638334
Epoch 1/3 : Batch 2/48 | loss = 14479824582732.208323 | root_mean_squared_error = 3805236.468701
Epoch 1/3 : Batch 3/48 | loss = nan | root_mean_squared_error = nan
Epoch 1/3 : Batch 4/48 | loss = nan | root_mean_squared_error = nan
Epoch 1/3 : Batch 5/48 | loss = nan | root_mean_squared_error = nan
......
```

The loss goes very high in the second batch and then becomes nan. The true outcome y does not contains very large values. The max y is less than 400.

On the other hand, I check the prediction output y_hat. The RNN returns some very high prediction, which leads to infinite.

However, I am still puzzled how to improve my model.

Comment: have you tried switching to cross entropy loss

Comment: did you try using `tanh` or `sigmoid` instead of `relu` to avoid large values?

Comment: @Julius This is a regression problem. Is cross entropy loss also applicable?

Comment: @S.Mohsensh I tried tanh. The problem is still there. I just tried to replace linear with relu on the output layer. It works but the loss does not decreases over epoch. All epoch has the same loss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is "kind of" solved by 1) changing the activation of the output layer from "linear" to "relu" and/or 2) decreasing the learning rate.

However, the predictions now are all zero.

Comment: relu is designed to output sparse vectors. It is used in output layer neither for classification (as it does not output probabilities), nor for regression (as most outputs are zeros due to the design). Keeping the last layer linear is a good choice for the last layer